Cannot open folder/read file on Windows file system
I am completely puzzled - I cannot access folder on my harddrive, despite of fact that I am administrator.
Drive is encrypted by bitlocker, which I unlock by entering password on startup.
I checked drive and no errors were found.
I run Total Commander as administrator. When I try to enter folder MISC, I get error

When I open security properties of folder I see this:

When I click advanced I see this:

When I try to take ownership by local user "vlado" who is administrator I get this error:


Can you advice please?
